# Which super constructor will be called? And is super constructor still invoked if i don't invoke a super constructor in subclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, super

```
public class Faculty extends Employee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Faculty();
    }

    public Faculty() {
        super(“faculty”);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
     private String name;
     public Employee() {
     name = “no name”;
     System.out.println("(3) Employee's no-arg constructor is invoked");
     }

     public Employee(String s) {
     name = s;
     System.out.println(s);
     }
}

class Person {
    //What if there was a parameterized constructor here
    // e.g. public Person(String s){
    //            ... code ...
    //      }
}
```

In the above Java code, if i leave the Person class blank, and call super constructor in Faculty class' no-arg constructor, Employee's constructor would be called. But what if there is a parameterized constructor in the Person class. Which super constructor will be called? Employee one or Person one?

And is super constructor still invoked if i don't invoke a super constructor in subclass?

Comment: Why not try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what if there is a parameterized constructor in the Person class.

If you do that, you get a nice compilation error.

If your super class constructor has a parameter, your subclass shall invoke `super(arguments)` where arguments matches the parameter.

If the super class constructor does not have any parameters, your child class will implicitly invoke `super()`. Hence we don't have to explicitly invoke `super()` again.

**Example:**

```
class GrandParent
{
    public GrandParent(String s){
        System.out.println("Calling my grandpa");
    }
}

class Parent extends GrandParent
{
    public Parent(){
        super("");
        System.out.println("Calling my pa");
    }   
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child(){
        //super() implicitly invoked
        System.out.println("Calling my child"); 
    }
}
```

Upon running the following:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Child();
    }
}
```

You get:

```
Calling my grandpa
Calling my pa
Calling my child
```

The above output answers your subsequent questions:

> Employee one or Person one?
>   And is super constructor still invoked if i don't invoke a super constructor in subclass?

Comment: No need to have a `String` argument on every constructor. You just need an actual argument to match the formal argument. For example, the `Child` constructor could be parameterless and begin with `super("I am a Child");`

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You are right, thanks for reminding. I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Employee` class won't compile if you add a parametrized constructor to `Person`, as the default, no-args constructor will not be implied anymore, but your `Employee` constructors would need to invoke it.

Now, if your `Person` class featured both a no-args and a `String`-parametrized constructor (with the same `Employee` implementation), your code would compile, and either invocation of `Employee`'s constructors would still invoke `Person`'s no-args constructor first.